# sas:how to add one column upon another column in sas?

Tags: sas

```
data exp;
input y a b c;
cards;
1 2 3 6
4 5 . 8
1 . . 8
2 4 6 9
. 4 6 3
;
run;
```

My requirement is to get this data set into single data set with say 3 new columns without the blank values.

output should look like this :

```
x y z
1 5 6
4 4 8
1 4 8 
2 3 9
2 6 3
```

Comment: Why do you need your data split into columns if it doesn't actually matter how many columns there are, or which column each entry ends up in? Is there something else you're trying to do with your data?

Comment: What relationship does that final dataset have to the initial one??

Comment: yes, I would like work further with the data set so formed.

Comment: @joe It does not have a relation with the previous dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
data _null_;
    set exp (obs=0) nobs=nobs;
    call symputx("nobs", nobs);
run;

proc transpose data=exp out=exp2;
run;

data exp3(keep=row final);
    set exp2;
    array col{&nobs};
    do i = 1 to &nobs;
        if col[i] ne . then do;
            row+1;
            if row = &nobs+1 then row = 1;
            final = col[i];
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;

proc sort data=exp3;
    by row;
run;

proc transpose data = exp3 out=exp4 (drop=_name_ row 
        rename=(col1=x col2=y col3=z col4=zz));
    by row;
run;
```

First I counted the observations in the starting data set and stored that to a macro variable (if you know it is always 5 you can skip this step and replace &nobs with 5). Then I transposed the data set so it is rotated 90 degrees. This allows me to then go through each number in order and output it to one long row, also adding a number for the row we want it to be in in the final output. Finally I transposed by row number to get the final output.

Comment: this is giving the data in a single column, but then how to split data into the required number of columns

Comment: The last step transposes the data into the required number of columns. The final data set given the code above is "exp4" with variables x, y, z, and zz. Let me know if that isn't displaying how you want it.